# Bitcoinj library on android hung on installing APK

Tags: java, android, bitcoinj

I am trying to get a basic running app that would use the bitcoinj library to create a wallet and sync. Very basic. I used bitcoinj library for my desktop application with no problems. When i try to make one for android it hangs on "...Installing APK" when trying to run it on my phone.

This is my code.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import org.bitcoinj.core.Context;
import org.bitcoinj.core.NetworkParameters;
import org.bitcoinj.core.listeners.DownloadProgressTracker;
import org.bitcoinj.kits.WalletAppKit;
import org.bitcoinj.params.TestNet3Params;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static NetworkParameters BTCparams = TestNet3Params.get();
    public static WalletAppKit BTCkit = new WalletAppKit(BTCparams,new File("."),"BTC-Test");
    private ProgressBar BTCProgress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BTCProgress = findViewById(R.id.BTCProgress);
        Context.propagate(new Context(BTCparams));
        DownloadProgressTracker BTCListener = new DownloadProgressTracker() {
            @Override
            public void progress(double pct, int blocksSoFar, Date date) {
                System.out.println("Syncing..."+pct+"%");
                BTCProgress.setProgress((int) pct);
            }
            @Override
            public void doneDownload() {
                System.out.println("Sync Done.");
                BTCProgress.setProgress(100);
            }
        };
        BTCkit.setDownloadListener(BTCListener).setBlockingStartup(false).startAsync().awaitRunning();
    }
}
```

This is my build.gradle in my app folder.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testapp.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'org.bitcoinj:bitcoinj-core:0.14.7'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.12'
}
```

I eventually get this dialog box.

[Dialog](https://ibb.co/dOCjuq)

When i click ok i get this error.

[Error](https://ibb.co/dL7W7A)

which brings you to here...

[Binder.java](https://ibb.co/kAdtLV)

I am stumped and cannot figure out why this isnt working. I suspect once i resolve this issue then my development will be a breeze. Please provide details as im still learning the android development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it to:

```
implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.25"
api "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25"
```

this also looks strange:

```
Context.propagate(new Context(BTCparams));
```

because it is not even `NULL`, but has no value.

Comment: the above comment was with context commented out. when i put it back in i get the exact same error.

Comment: *Bumpity Bump Bump*

Comment: @Chris this comes from missing native assembly... eg. when building `*.so` for `armeabi` and then trying to run that on a `x86` emulator image - or the other way around, with an ARM device. you might have to install the `NDK` to even have the tool-chain available to build it.

Comment: Can you walk me through the process?

Comment: this a) exceeds the scope of the question and b) that `build.gradle` does not even build any native assembly... which might come from some `jar` in the `libs` directory. please accept the answer for the actual question and feel free to ask a new one question, for the new one problem. searching that error message might already provide some clue.