# missing binaries for apk to install on device

Tags: android, bitcoinj

I have looked at this article

[[INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36414219/install-failed-no-matching-abis-failed-to-extract-native-libraries-res-113)

But i was unable to get any resolution.

right now this is my code.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testapp.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'arm64-v8a'
            universalApk true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation('me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9') { exclude module: 'support-v4' }
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    implementation 'org.bitcoinj:bitcoinj-core:0.14.7'
    api 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.12'
}
```

And also my mainactivity

```
public class MainPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static NetworkParameters BTCparams = TestNet3Params.get();
    public static WalletAppKit BTCkit = new WalletAppKit(BTCparams,new File("."),"BTC-Test");

    static String[] account;
    static String[] server;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView tVBTCPer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tVBTCPer);
        TextView tVNull = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tVNull);
        tVNull.setText(System.getProperty("os.arch"));
        DownloadProgressTracker BTCListener = new DownloadProgressTracker() {
            @Override
            public void progress(double pct, int blocksSoFar, Date date) {
                tVBTCPer.setText((int) pct+"%");
            }
            @Override
            public void doneDownload() {
                tVBTCPer.setText("100%");
            }
        };
        BTCkit.setDownloadListener(BTCListener).setBlockingStartup(false).startAsync().awaitRunning();
}
```

I used this library to make java applications for pc/linux and it works fine. But when im trying to compile this for android to be usable it gets hung up trying to install the apk onto my device.

my os.arch is aarch64. I also have a previous post in stackoverflow to help give it some context.

[Bitcoinj library on android hung on installing APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53620658/bitcoinj-library-on-android-hung-on-installing-apk)

I am not entirely sure what library i would need to help this apk install onto my device.

Comment: you need to have the ARM version of native libraries your app is using to run it on ARM device.

Comment: yes but where do i get that library?

Comment: do you have any native libraries used directly? E.g. have any `.so` files included into your project? First you need to understand which libraries are causing problems.

Comment: i have libjSSC-2.8.so and android-aarch64.jar files. i just don't know how to add this in my dependencies. i put it in my library folder and included it in my build.gradle but im still getting the issue not being able to install APK

Comment: which architecture is `libjSSC-2.8.so` for?

Comment: aarch64 is the library